# Does local reducibility imply global reducibility of universal covering?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a locally reducible complete Riemannian manifold, that is, for any $p \in M$, we can find an open set $U$ around $p$ and two Riemannian manifolds $X$ and $Y$ such that $U$ is isometric to $X \times Y$. If $\widetilde{M}$ is the universal covering of $M$, can we find two Riemannian manifolds $\widetilde{X}$ and $\widetilde{Y}$ such that $\widetilde{M}$ is isometric to $\widetilde{X} \times \widetilde{Y}$?

Comment: You at least need completeness. Otherwise just take any non-rectangular simply connected region in the plane.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add completeness.